# Acer Aspire 5755g randomly shuts down when moving the machine

Tags: windows-7, laptop, shutdown, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire 5755g that will sit and run fine on my desk but whenever I try to lift my laptop to another location it will randomly shut down. 
It is not overheating because I can turn it back on straight away and it will sometimes happen if it is the first time I have turned it on for the day. 
The only thing that causes the problem is when I lift and move the laptop. It can sit at a desk fine or I can even bump/tap the laptop case on purpose and it will still run until I lift/move it to another location.

Windows 7 64Bit ultimate. Fully charged battery.

Comment: Does it happen if powered up just to CMOS or an alternative operating system like an Unbuntu LIVE cd ?

Comment: I don't have any alternative operating system to test this on sorry.

Comment: But when you boot into the CMOS, the BIOS menus, does it still shutdown in the same manner?

Comment: I have not tested this. I will do that soon as I am leaving work now. Will there be any issues if it shuts down in the bios menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely due to loose screws on the reverse of the case. There is a safety feature which kills power on Acer laptops when the hardware detects the case is open (and power is on). By tightening the screws on the reverse of the laptop (hard!), the problem magically goes away. Since the screws are self-loosing, this may need to be repeated every few years.

The problem (with resolution) is [described in great detail here](https://superuser.com/questions/1008809/laptop-shuts-down-suddenly-when-running-on-battery).

Comment: I would agree that now after a period of time I have actually seen multiple screws fall out and that tightening the screws could be the answer.

Comment: @WillNZ "could be" or "is" the answer?

Comment: @Zeeshan look into the future for me and tell me if its fixed the problem... After tightening/replacing the missing screws the laptop is working fine but hard to say if this is the fix or not as the problem happens sometimes and not others. The reason why I have marked this as the answer is because for now this is working and I have found multiple questions about Acer laptops with the same issue as mine and that was the fix for them.

Answer (score 1):

Open the ram slot from back and either tighten the screw or insert a small paper so that the button doesn't remain loose for power (mainly for acer laptop maybe different for other laptops)

Answer (score -1):

This may be an issue due to damaged power connectors/cabling inside your laptop, or a loose battery terminal in the battery compartment, or may be an internal damage to the battery itself (cells may have got damaged due to physical jerks maybe). Testing if it shuts down at BIOS also may not make any difference as it shuts down due to physical movement, nothing related to Windows. What I can sense is most probably it is a hardware issue and your laptop should be checked for this by an authorized hardware technician.

Comment: I pulled the laptop apart and gave everything a wiggle then put it back together and it all works fine. I'll give you the answer as no one else left one.

Comment: OK, then it might have been a loose internal power cable, which may have got adjusted while re-assembling the things. Still nothing sure.